# Seeding one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, seed

I am creating the API (Laravel 5) for an RPG game, and am trying to seed data.

Each level contains many quests, and each quest belongs to one level.

Looking through the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), I only see relationships for inserting related model data for one:one (`associate`), and many:many (`sync, attach`), but nothing for the example of one:many (`level has many quests, but quests only have one level`).

You can see below in the seeding that I am trying to randomly associate multiple quests to levels. I've also tried `attach` and `sync` but get the errors

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()

and

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Level model:

```
public function quests()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Quest::class);
}
```

Quest model:

```
public function levels()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Level::class);
}
```

Level Seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $levels = $this->createLevels();

    $quests = Quest::all()->toArray();

    /*
     * Randomly join level id with associated quest ids
     */
    foreach ($levels as $level) {

        $level->quests()->associate($quests[rand(0, count($quests) - 1)]['id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `save()` method, as stated by @Mithredate.

```
foreach ($levels as $level) {
    $quest->levels()->save($level);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use eloquent `save()` method. You can find the documentations [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)